# Printing arabic strings in android

Tags: android, fonts

In my application I need to add some string to a list and print them back. Problem is when I print them I can see the letters has inter change whithing the word.The word is in Arabic. (before 4.2 android doesnt support natively for Arabic).
What I tried was using several Arabic rendering classes such as fursi class and Arabi utility class. Nothing is helped me.

Here is the word `٣.. ما زاد على`  actually this part `٣..` should be the first it always goes to right as I have shown. Is there way to solve this thing. this is the one and only bug to hold the application to add to market :(

Answer (score 1):

Oh, ouch! Arabic is worse than Hebrew in this aspect because Arabic has its own digits! Right!

I once had a similar problem on Windows, with symbols that weren't treated exactly as Hebrew but also not exactly as non-Hebrew. The *only* way I found to fix this was to split the string into two - print the problematic symbols (your 300) and then print the rest of the string.

I thought that with Unicode things has gotten better. I guess not always.

UPDATE: In a comment you said the translation of the string was 3.. . In Arabic, zero and a dot look very similar (which is why I confused a dot with a zero). Perhaps the person responsible of the input typed it wrong, not being fluent in Arabic, as well? 3.. doesn't make a lot of sense (3. does, and so does 300, but 3.. ?). Check the input, it might be wrong, and that can confuse the layout algorithm.

Comment: I don't know Arabic. When I translated the string in google translate, it shows `3..` . this is a zakat applicaiton. Now I run it on mobile deveices but I see same issue again. But on emulator it works as I expected. Even in SO and google translation, it changes to my problematic style to automatically.However, I thought to set it as a image in my application spinner.

Comment: Can you guess why emulator and mobile device behave differently?

Comment: The emulator is known not to be a perfect emulation of the device. You might even find another device that behaves better. RTL is a big pain.

Comment: Oh, and another tip. When you want to develop something in a language you don't know, you *really* want someone who knows the language next to you. I once translated a program to Japanese - the Japanese speaking person found many embarrassing mistakes, even though I only copied strings.

Answer (score 0):

I can't technically understand the reason behind my action to correct above issue. However this is it . `   I reverse the word and separated letters by "+" and added to the list.It is amazing !